# Finding the range of the function $f(x) = 3-4x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $f(x)=3-4x$, $x\in \left \{ -1,0,1,2 \right \}$

My working,

When $x=-1$, $f(x)=7$

When $x=2,f(x)=-5$

So the range:$-5\leq f(x)\leq 7$.

Am I correct?

Comment: If I am reading the question correctly, f(x) is only defined for four values of x (so its range is at most four numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the domain of $f$ is a set of four values, we have $f(-1) = 7$, $f(0) = 3, f(-1) = -1$ and $f(2) = -5$ so the range of $f$ is the set $$\text{range}(f) = \left\{-5, -1, 3, 7\right\}.$$